# How to remove .html folder-name in URL without interfering with js files using htaccess?

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, url

Format of the URL:

```
example.com/pages/contact.html
```

and want:

```
example.com/contact
```

Removing `.html` and folder from the URL.

Here is a simple piece of code below:

```
RewriteEngine On


#Here is the code for removing /pages/ and .html from url

Options -MultiViews

#Redirect any "direct" requests to the `/pages` directory
#To remove the directory from the URL-path.
#Also removes the ".html" extension (if present)

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^pages(/.*?)(?:\.html)?$ $1 [R=301,L]

#Check if the requested resource exists in the /pages subdirectory.
#If so, rewrite the request to that subdirectory.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1 -f
RewriteRule (.+\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif))$ /pages/$1 [L]


#Check if the requested PHP file exists in the /pages subdirectory
#if requesting a URL that does not already have a file extension.
#NB: Assumes the URL-path does not otherwise contain dots.
#If so, rewrite the request to that subdirectory appending ".html"
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /pages/$1.html [L]

#Here is the end of the code for removing /pages/ and .html from URL





#Here the code for removing index from the tool

RewriteBase /pages/tool1/

#remove index.php from URLs
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.html$ $1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]

# Here is the end for removing index from the tool



#Here is the code for running even .html site to php

#HTID:15533125: DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW

php_value display_errors 1

#DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE HTID:15533125:

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm 

#Here is the end for running even .html site to PHP
```

Here 3 main blocks of code are there

1. To remove .html and /pages/ folder from the URL
2. To remove index.html from subfolder like - example.com/tool1/index.php => example.com/tool1
3. To force run .html files into PHP too.

Now after implementing this code in the .htaccess file it works nicely like removes the /pages/ also the index.html in the tool1 file and also runs the .html into PHP but the problem occurs that the forms don't work that have action attribute and also javascript doesn't run.

I have a newsletter section[using js to send emails to google sheets seen in tutorials] at the end of the homepage where the email is taken but when I click on the button, it redirects again to the homepage, and also the tool doesn't work looks like the js is not applied.

Please answer...

Comment: When you use SEO URLs like `site.com/page/subpage` it will break relative URLs. This leads to your scripts, CSS, and images to not load (404 not found). Add `<base href="https://www.example.com">` between `<head>` and `</head>`. Replace "https://www.example.com" with your full website.

Comment: Please could you elaborate on this? Thanks!

Comment: Add a base tag on your pages like I showed above. This base tag fixes the 404 problems your having.

Comment: So could i use /filename without using www.example.com in the href

Comment: That's correct. Try it out.

Comment: See also this question on the Webmasters Stack: [.htaccess rewrite URL leads to missing CSS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css)